# What does "have" means in Farmer words?

Tags: meaning

In English Romantic Drama Movie "[Days of Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_of_Heaven)", Farm Foreman say this words to Farmer.

> Farmer: You don't like them, do ya? You never **have**.
>
> Farm Foreman: I don't think they're honest people. As a matter of
>   fact,I think they're a pair of con artists.

Actually sentence ends with **have**, How to understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is conversational elision, where the last word or two is left off because it's very strongly implied or is repeating a predicate or complement/object thereof that was expressed a few words ago.

The full sentence would be "You don't like them, do ya?  You never have [liked them]."

Also "You never have." is a somewhat well-known set of words at least in AmE speech that points back to a sentence just said.